# Malformed record literal when inserting a custom data type

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, custom-data-type

I'm having problems inserting a record containing a custom data type in PostgreSQL 13, using JDBC. I've created the table and custom data type 'address', and following the [java custom mapping tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlcustommapping.html), I've implemented the SQLData interface on the Address class.

When I try to insert, I get a PSQLException as shown below.

```
INSERT INTO teachers(name, surname, address) VALUES('Jorge','Romero','model.Address@75881071')
RETURNING *
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: malformed record literal: "model.Address@75881071"
  Detail: Missing left parenthesis.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130)
    at PostgresqlTest/application.DBTestMain.main(DBTestMain.java:39)
```

This is my code:

```
package model;

public class Teacher {
    
    Integer teacherID;
    String name;
    String surname;
    Address address;
    
    public Teacher() {
        
    }
    
    public Teacher(String name, String surname, Address address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Teacher(Integer teacherID, String name, String surname, Address address) {
        this.teacherID = teacherID;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Integer getTeacherID() {
        return teacherID;
    }

    public void setTeacherID(Integer teacherID) {
        this.teacherID = teacherID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

```
package model;

import java.sql.SQLData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLInput;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

public class Address implements SQLData {

    private String streetType;
    private String streetName;
    private Integer houseNumber;
    private String additionalInfo;
    private String town;
    private String province;
    private String postCode;
    private String sql_type = "public.address";

    public Address() {

    }

    public Address(String streetType, String streetName, Integer housenumber, String additionalinfo, String town,
            String province, String postCode) {
        this.streetType = streetType;
        this.streetName = streetName;
        this.houseNumber = housenumber;
        this.additionalInfo = additionalinfo;
        this.town = town;
        this.province = province;
        this.postCode = postCode;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return sql_type;
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        streetType = stream.readString();
        streetName = stream.readString();
        houseNumber = stream.readInt();
        additionalInfo = stream.readString();
        town = stream.readString();
        province = stream.readString();
        postCode = stream.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeString(streetType);
        stream.writeString(streetName);
        stream.writeInt(houseNumber);
        stream.writeString(additionalInfo);
        stream.writeString(town);
        stream.writeString(province);
        stream.writeString(postCode);
    }

    public String getStreetType() {
        return streetType;
    }

    public void setStreetType(String streetType) {
        this.streetType = streetType;
    }

    public String getStreetName() {
        return streetName;
    }

    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
    }

    public Integer getHouseNumber() {
        return houseNumber;
    }

    public void setHouseNumber(Integer houseNumber) {
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
    }

    public String getAdditionalInfo() {
        return additionalInfo;
    }

    public void setAdditionalInfo(String additionalInfo) {
        this.additionalInfo = additionalInfo;
    }

    public String getTown() {
        return town;
    }

    public void setTown(String town) {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.province = province;
    }

    public String getPostCode() {
        return postCode;
    }

    public void setPostCode(String postCode) {
        this.postCode = postCode;
    }

    public String getSql_type() {
        return sql_type;
    }

    public void setSql_type(String sql_type) {
        this.sql_type = sql_type;
    }
}
```

```
package util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Map;

public class DBManager {
    private final String USER = "postgres";
    private final String PASS = "admin";
    private final String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/teachersDB"; 
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Statement st;
    
    public void createConnection() {
        try{
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASS);
         
         }catch(SQLException ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
    
    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
    
    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
                if(connection!=null && !connection.isClosed())
                    connection.close();
                                    
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    
    public void createDataTypes() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
            String sentence = "CREATE TYPE address AS (streetType VARCHAR, "
                                                    + "streetName VARCHAR, "
                                                    + "houseNumber INT, "
                                                    + "additionalInfo VARCHAR, "
                                                    + "town VARCHAR, "
                                                    + "province VARCHAR, "
                                                    + "postCode VARCHAR(5))";
            st = connection.createStatement();
            st.execute(sentence);
            
            //Create custom mapping for Address object
            Map map = connection.getTypeMap();
            map.put("public.address", Class.forName("model.Address"));
            connection.setTypeMap(map);
    }

    public void createTables() {
        createConnection();
        try {       
            String statement = "CREATE TABLE teachers (teacherID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,"
                                                    + "name VARCHAR, " 
                                                    + "surname VARCHAR,"
                                                    + "address ADDRESS);";
            st = connection.createStatement();
            st.execute(statement);
            System.out.println("Teachers table created");
            
            closeConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
package application;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Types;

import dao.TeacherDAO;
import model.Address;
import model.Teacher;
import util.DBManager;

public class DBTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DBManager db = new DBManager();
            db.createConnection();

            Address a = new Address("Calle","Mayor",1,"5D","Cartagena","Murcia","30201");
            Teacher t = new Teacher(0,"Jorge","Romero",a);

            String SQL = "INSERT INTO teachers(name, surname, address) "
                    + "VALUES(?,?,?);";
            db.createConnection();
            Connection cn = db.getConnection();
            
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ps = cn.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            ps.setString(1, t.getName());
            ps.setString(2, t.getSurname());
            //Set the address object
            ps.setObject(3, t.getAddress(),Types.OTHER);
            
            System.out.println(ps.toString());

            ps.executeUpdate();
            int teacherID;
            
            ResultSet result = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
            if (result.next()) {
                teacherID = result.getInt(1);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated because I'm completely stuck at this point.

Comment: Looks like the error is a missing left bracket in `TeacherDAO` (code not given)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I posted the stack trace from the full project, instead of the example I created to demonstrate the problem. I've updated it now and also printed the prepared statement to show the statement it's producing. It says it's due to a missing left bracket but the issue seems to be that it's simply passing the address object name as a string instead of actually doing anything with it.

Comment: Given the error message, your code is attempting to insert the default `toString()` of the object (`'model.Address@75881071'`). The PostgreSQL JDBC driver does not support type maps or the `SQLData` interface, so what you're trying to do will not work.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no built-in support for custom types in the PostgreSQL JDBC driver, and the only way to use it is to implement the string serialization/deserialization equivalent to what PostgreSQL would do, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59157230/466862)

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel! I've changed the column type to json and used GSon to handle the object conversion and it's working perfectly now. I didn't realise that the JDBC driver didn't support custom types, I just assumed it would being as it's a feature supported by PostgreSQL.